# IIS8 allow access to all subdirectories

Tags: iis, iis-8

How can I allow access to all subdirectories using web.config? I know how to allow access per-directory but not to all child directories at once.

Answer (score 0):

Settings in web.config are inherited to all sub-directories by default, unless another web.config in a lower directory overrides them. So there is no need to do anything.

What exactly do you mean by 'allow access'?